# Laravel: redirect to the previous submit page to edit form

Tags: php, laravel, forms, redirect, button

When the form gets submitted you get to a site where all the inputs from the form will be displayed again to check it.
If you want to change anything, there's a button to "send you back" to the form with all the data you've already typed in.

How do I achieve this?

I've already tried with:

```
<a href="{{ url()->previous() }}"<button type="submit" class="button btn-sm">Bearbeiten</button></a>
```

I do get back to the form-site, but the input-fields are empty(of course).

I have seen something with `redirect()->back()->withInput();` and I wonder if I can somehow use it to save the input values without a controller method; just a simple redirect back to the previous page with the input-data still there.

This is one of the input-fields:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">
```

Since I'm a newbie with Laravel I don't really know how to achieve what I'm trying to do and I haven't found anything really helpful yet.

Comment: May want to have a look [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#old-input). I'm way behind on laravel but this should be a good starting point.

Comment: On modern browsers if the user clicked the browser's back button, he should find the old data.

Comment: `window.history.back()` - In Javascript.  `<a onClick="window.history.back()"....`

Answer (score 1):

I would just do it the old fashioned way

```
<a onClick="window.history.back()" ....</a>
```

That way the Users browser history is the same as if they simple pushed the back button.

Comment: but just imagine, you're filling in this form and then got to another site on a different tab. And after this you return to the submitted form-site that shows you your inputs and want to change it. Wouldn't this send you to the other side you were on the other tab?

Comment: No, it's just like hitting the back button in the browser.  History is tracked per tab.  And your not adding to the history.  By redirecting back, your probably adding another page to the history.  So if the user hits back who knows where they go.  Prolly redirect loop. "Where you have to hit back 2x".  It's actually more organic this way as it pops off the last part of the browser history.

Comment: I just tried this out, but after reloading the page that displays the form submits, it didn't work anymore. So I guess this solution is good, but not perfect

Comment: It works the same as the back button, if you reload the page the back button will do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry @ofmiceandmoon 
My previous answer was not good because I wasn't getting your question correctly. Here is the right answer:

Let's say you have a view named "form". In your form put:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="{{ request()->get('name') }}">
```

And in your controller you want to go to another view named "display" and show the input value:

```
$name = $request->input('name');
return view('layouts.display')->with('name', $name);
```

And in your display view:

```
<a href="{{ url()->previous() }}?name={{ $name }}"><button type="submit" class="button btn-sm">Bearbeiten</button></a>
```

I hope this does the trick.

Comment: Hi, @ofmiceandmoon if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark.